# retreive key from nested dict based on value, where key names are unknown

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
{
  'foo': {
    'name': 'bar',
    'options': None,
    'type': 'qux'
  },
  'baz': {
    'name': 'grault',
    'options': None,
    'type': 'plugh'
  },
}
```

The names of the top level keys are unknown at runtime. I am unable to figure out how to get the name of the top level key where the value of `type` is `plugh`. I have tried all kinds of iterators, loops, comprehensions etc, but i'm not great with Python. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried all kinds of iterators, loops, comprehensions etc,", please show one of these attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating over the dict keys and check for the element

```py
for key in d:
    if(d[key]['type'] == 'plugh'):
        print(key)
```

```
baz
```

Comment: This is imo the cleanest answer. Why are the brackets required around the if condition?

Comment: It's kind of my personal liking, haha

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for key, inner_dict in dict_.items():
    if inner_dict['type'] == 'plugh':
        print(key)
```

Or if you a one liner to get the first key matching the condition:

```
key = next(key for key, inner_dict in dict_.items() if inner_dict['type'] == 'plugh')
print(key)
```

output:

```
baz
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over your data like this:

```
def top_level_key(search_key, data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if value['type'] == search_key:
            return key

print(top_level_key('plugh', data_dict))
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides running loop to filter the target, you have another option to use jsonpath, which is quite like xPath

```
# pip install jsonpath-ng==1.5.2
# python 3.6
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

dct = {
    'foo': {
        'name': 'bar',
        'options': None,
        'type': 'qux'
    },
    'baz': {
        'name': 'grault',
        'options': None,
        'type': 'plugh'
    },
}

parse_str = '$[?@.type="plugh"]'
jsonpath_expr = parse(parse_str)
jsonpath_results = jsonpath_expr.find(dct)
if len(jsonpath_results) > 0:
    result = jsonpath_results[0].value
    print(result)
    # {'name': 'grault', 'options': None, 'type': 'plugh'}
else:
    result = None
```

Ref: https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/ to find out more stynax about jsonpath